# status bar not visible in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, statusbar

IE9 by default does not show status bar.  Users can make it visible by going into the View/Toolbars menu, but how can we set this programmatically client side?

I tried passing `status=1` in `window.open` method but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`status=yes` should do the trick... you can find this kind of stuff out faster with google.